# Save and restore keras model GRU layers hidden states while predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using keras with tensorflow backend.

My model is:

```
X_input = Input(name="x_input", batch_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 1, len(alphabet_dict)))
GRU_layer, hs = GRU(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, stateful=True, return_state=True)(X_input)
GRU_layer2, hs2 = GRU(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, stateful=True, return_state=True)(GRU_layer)
y = Dense(len(alphabet_dict), activation="softmax", name="y")(GRU_layer2)
model = Model(inputs=[X_input], outputs=[y, hs, hs2])
model.compile(loss={"y": categorical_crossentropy}, optimizer="adam", metrics=["acc"])
```

Save it after several of epochs. Then in player script restore this from checkpoint, and make independent from batch_size model with only one input:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = load_model(filepath=model_file, compile=True)
    old_weights = model.get_weights()
    del model

    X_input = Input(name="x_input", batch_shape=(1, 1, len(alphabet_dict)))
    GRU_layer, hs = GRU(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, stateful=True, return_state=True)(X_input)
    GRU_layer2, hs2 = GRU(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.25, recurrent_dropout=0.25, stateful=True, return_state=True)(GRU_layer)
    y = Dense(len(alphabet_dict), activation="softmax", name="y")(GRU_layer2)
    model = Model(inputs=[X_input], outputs=[y, hs, hs2])
    model.compile(loss={"y": categorical_crossentropy}, optimizer="adam", metrics=["acc"])
    model.set_weights(old_weights)
```

So then i predict with model:

```
prediction = model.predict(np_utils.to_categorical(input_idx, len(alphabet_dict)).reshape(1,1,len(alphabet_dict)))
prediction[0] - is model output "y"
prediction[1] - is GRU_layer hidden state hs
prediction[2] - is GRU_layer2 hidden state hs2
```

So I can "read" hidden states for my GRU layers.
But then I need something like "branching". I need to save my current hidden states and then predict several different inputs for my model from THIS statement.

I need something like that:

- 1) predict, predict, predict, predict, ....,  - here i predict one by
  one inputs, use theese outputs and accumulate model inner hidden
  states.
- 2) save model states on that step (step #500 for example)
- 3) use #501_1 input for my model. get and save model output and model
  inner hidden states.
- 4) load model inner states from step #500
- 5) use #501_2 input for my model. get and save model output and model
  inner hidden states.
- 6) choose best output, and depending on this choose correct #501 node.
- 7) like 1 - "predict, predict, ...."

I hope you understand my idea. It's important thing for me, because I don't want predict all from begin for each branch.

To be honest, python script player for model is not my point.
I export model to C++ format. Then I load it in C++ code and it's more faster then python interpretation.
So in ideal I need both solutions, for python and for C++ player.